# Java Collectors.reducing implementation

Tags: java, lambda, collectors, reducing

```
int val = integerList.stream().collect(
        Collectors.reducing(0, a1 -> a1 * 5, (a1, a2) -> a1 + a2));
```

The above code does the reduction operation.Transforming the stream of integers and the aggregation function to return Integer . **I couldn't comprehend the below code and the internal implementation of the reduction operation.How Java could perform the below Stateful function**? Thank you!

```
java.util.stream.Collectors:reducing method
    public static <T, U>
    Collector<T, ?, U> reducing(U identity,
                                Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper,
                                BinaryOperator<U> op) {
        return new CollectorImpl<>(
                boxSupplier(identity),
                (a, t) -> { a[0] = op.apply(a[0], mapper.apply(t)); },
                (a, b) -> { a[0] = op.apply(a[0], b[0]); return a; },
                a -> a[0], CH_NOID);
    }
```

May be, I will clarify my question little better. How the above implementation gets the stream of data. Does a[0],b[0] refers the Stream of data? I believe the above is providing functional implementation to supplier and accumulator. I wanted to understand how the reduction process works through the code.

Comment: Did you go through the documentation? What didn't make sense there?

Comment: Documentation tells about 'what' can be done. I am seeking clarification about How can be done.

Comment: Are you asking how the implementation works?

Comment: Now one could say: "Look at the code of the `CollectorImpl` class", but actually, it only combines the given `supplier`, `accumulator`, `combiner` and `finisher`, and all the magic happens in the `ReferencePipeline` implementation. Beyond that, you'd have to say more clearly what the question is (also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html , if you haven't yet)

Comment: Even though the JVM code is well written, it's often difficult to read because of the level of abstraction and complexity. You need to be very specific. "the internal implementation of the reduction operation" is not clearly defined.

Comment: "How Java could perform the below Stateful function?" `a` and `b` are arrays `T[]` where the intermediate state is saved

Comment: Yes @Lino.I am asking about the implementation

Comment: Thanks @Marco13 and Andrew Tobiliko. ReferencedPipeline is the good lead.I should probably see more into StreamSupport class. That is what I meant Internal implementation.Before I realized, got down votes

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-java-streams-3-brian-goetz/ This link is very useful

Comment: You should look at [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction). It shows simple equivalent code to explain the logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function takes three arguments:

- The first one is an identity. When reducing a stream, you have to start somewhere (otherwise, what would be the result of reducing an empty list?). The identity is the object applied to the first argument of the first reduction operation in the chain
- The second one is a mapper. `reducing()` is a generalized operation - you can reduce elements of a stream of type `T` into a final result of type `U`, so you have to give an intermediate operation that provides a type `U` element from a type `T` element. If `T == U` and you don't want a transformation, you can provide an identity function here
- The third argument is the reduction function - this is the one applied to elements of the stream in sequence, starting from the *identity*

So, as an example:

If you want to just summarize the elements of an `Integer` stream into an integer, you could use `Collectors.reducing(0, x -> x, (x, y) -> x + y)`.

If you want to summarize the lengths of `String`s in a `String` stream, you could use `Collectors.reducing(0, String::length, (x, y) -> x + y)`.

If you want to get the maximum `Double` from a string of `Double`s, but no less than `Math.PI`, you could use `Collectors.reducing(Math.PI, x -> x, Math::max)`.

Also, if you want your reduction to be stateful, remember that you can use as a reductor a reference to a method inside an object. That way, the object can be used to keep the state. For example, here's a "taxing reductor" that adds 1 "tax" to its score every 100 additions:

```
public class Taxer implements BinaryOperator<Integer> {
 int counter = 0;

 @Override
 public Integer apply(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
  counter++;
  if (counter % 100 == 0) {
   return i1 + i2 + 1;
  } else {
   return i1 + i2;
  }
 }
}

...

Taxer t = new Taxer();

...

.collect(Collectors.reducing(0, x -> x, t);
```

The same can be extended using to implement complex cases like `groupingBy`:

```
Map<String, Integer> output = Stream.of("this", "word", "is", "the", "best")
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x-> x.substring(0, 1),
            Collectors.reducing(0, x-> x.length(), (x, y)-> x + y)));
```

Here first the input string is grouped based on the character they start with and then the lengths are summed

Comment: Great answer, the 3 points were the one's that helped me through. I was facing a problem with the GroupBy with reduce. I added a sample to that as well in your code. +1 for the 3 points cheers

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I understood reducing operation.(Than just knowing).

Comment: Thanks for the votes of confidence, good to know that it was actually useful :>